# Erro al realizar Intent: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

Tengo un problema usando putExtra y los Intent, ocurre qué quiero pasar valores de 3 métodos que calculan el volumen de un cubo, un cilindro y una esfera, todo bien hasta que doy click en el botón calcular, debería iniciar otra activity y mostrar los resultados ahí pero no lo hace, la aplicación crashea y me manda el siguiente error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.volumenes, PID: 6896
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.volumenes/com.example.volumenes.Result}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
```

Código del primer `Activity`.

```
package com.example.volumenes;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText lCubo, A`introducir el código aquí`rCili, AlCili, rEsf;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lCubo = findViewById(R.id.edtCuboL);
        ArCili = findViewById(R.id.edtCilA);
        AlCili = findViewById(R.id.edtCilR);
        rEsf = findViewById(R.id.edtEsfR);

        btn = findViewById(R.id.buttonC);

        btn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            double p = volC();
            double j = volCil();
            double l = volEsf();

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Result.class);
            i.putExtra("Cubo", p);
            i.putExtra("Cilindro", j);
            i.putExtra("Esfera", l);
            startActivity(i);
        });
    }

    public double volC(){
        String y = lCubo.getText().toString();
        double x = Double.parseDouble(y);
        return Math.pow(x, 3);
    }

    public double volCil(){
        String a = ArCili.getText().toString();
        String b = AlCili.getText().toString();

        double y = Double.parseDouble(a);
        double x = Double.parseDouble(b);
        double z = (Math.pow(y, 2)) * 3.1416;
        double r = z * x;
        return r;
    }

    public double volEsf(){
        double r = Double.parseDouble(rEsf.getText().toString());
        double v = (4 / 3) * (3.1416 * (Math.pow(r, 3)));
        return v;
    }


}
```

Código del segundo `Activity`:

```
package com.example.volumenes;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Result extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView c, cil, e;
    Button btn;
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

        c = findViewById(R.id.textViewCubo);
        cil = findViewById(R.id.textViewCili);
        e = findViewById(R.id.textViewEsfera);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.buttonBack);

        String a = getIntent().getStringExtra("Cubo");
        String b = getIntent().getStringExtra("Cilindro");
        String k = getIntent().getStringExtra("Esfera");

        double cc = Double.parseDouble(a);
        double ci = Double.parseDouble(b);
        double ee = Double.parseDouble(k);

        c.setText("Volumen del cubo: " + cc);
        cil.setText("Volumen del cilindro: " + ci);
        e.setText("Volumen de la esfera: " + ee);

        btn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        });

    }
}
```

Intente modificar la declaración de los putExtra, al momento de usar los métodos, cuando recupero al información del intent en la otra activity y no pasa nada, me da el mismo error!.
¡Gracias!

Comment: Hola, los valores se envían y se reciben sin problema, el problema se genera en otra parte, donde estas usando trim() ?

Comment: Si es en el otro activity donde me genera el error

Comment: agrega el mensaje del LogCat donde diga "Caused by:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que **el problema es que envías los valores inicialmente como tipo `Double`, pero los recibes como `String` usando `getStringExtra()`** , realiza el siguiente cambio al enviar los valores, conviértelos a tipo String usando  `String.ValueOf()`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Result.class);
i.putExtra("Cubo", String.ValueOf(p));
i.putExtra("Cilindro", String.ValueOf(j));
i.putExtra("Esfera", String.ValueOf(l));
startActivity(i);
```